# ng-show not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
   {{showSubHeader}}
            <div ng-show="showSubHeader" class="topPull" draggable >
            <button class="button-icon ion-bag"></button>
                           </div>       
        </div>
```

The expressions `{{showSubHeader}}` changes from true to false and false to true just fine.

showSubHeader has a boolean value .

i.e `showSubHeader=true` or  `showSubHeader=false`

The value changes are being picked up by angular . As I change the value, I see in console that ng-show expression changes but it does not hide the element even if it is ng-show="false".

How do I fix this? What seems wrong?>

Edit: draggable is a directive that looks like this:

```
.directive('draggable', function ($animate) {
  return function(scope, element) {
       var startX = 0, startY = 0, x = 0, y = 0;

        var el = element[0];
        console.log(el)
        el.draggable = true;
        element.css({
       position: 'relative',
       cursor: 'pointer'
      });
        el.addEventListener(
            'dragstart',
            function(e) {


          element.addClass("animated slideInDown")
                return false;
            },
            false
        );

        el.addEventListener(
            'dragend',
            function(e) {

          element.addClass("animated slideInUp")
             scope.checkBill();
                return false;
            },
            false
        );
    }
})
```

checkBill

```
$scope.checkBill= function(){
    $scope.$apply(function(){
       $scope.showSubHeader=false;

    })
     $state.go('menu.TotalBill', {}, {inherit: true, notify:true})
  }
```

Comment: just make a jsfiddle and realise that it works ;)

Comment: What is your topPull class doing?

Comment: Must be something else...

Comment: Are you 100% sure `typeof showSubHeader === boolean`? If it evaluates to a String, it will always show (`"false" === true`).

Comment: I know. I am not even new to angular. I understand how things work here and I am not using it for the first time. yet I am completely stuck with this

Comment: @Marcelo: Yes, Only value that I have assigned to it is true or false without any quotes s =o yes, It's boolean only

Comment: @DavidL: It's a css class with margins.I checked and took it off as well but same issue

Comment: What "draggable" is doing? Maybe this plugin has copied the element for other structure, and your ng-show doesn't reflect to the new structure

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo: Updated the question with draggable code. Please check.There is nothing much that it really does.

Comment: have you tried ng-show="showSubHeader === true"  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to isolate ng-show:

```
<div ng-show="showSubHeader">
    <div class="topPull" draggable >
        <button class="button-icon ion-bag"></button>
    </div>       
</div>
```

Comment: Try to invert the logic, using ng-hide="! showSubHeader"... or try to use ng-if.

Comment: I had a script cdn that I had added some time back and basically it  was interfering with it. Removed it and everything got fixed. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<div ng-show="showSubHeader === true" class="topPull" draggable >
      <button class="button-icon ion-bag"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: and ng-show="showSubHeader === 'true' "  ? ng-show="showSubHeader !== false " ?